# Spark format number without rounding

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a number for example `123.456789` which i wan to convert this to `123.45`.

if i use `format_number` this is rounding the decimal always to `123.46`

How can i achieve this with out rounding. I tried the below one but i am afraid that it may cause when i have numbers like `1234` or `0.1267`

```
functions.concat(split(col(Number), "\\.").getItem(0), substring(split(col(Number), "\\.").getItem(1),1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
format_number(floor(Number * 100) / 100, 2)
```

Only works for positive numbers. For negative numbers, you'd want to use `ceiling` instead of `floor`, so use `if()` or `case when`, depending on Spark version.

```
format_number(if (Number < 0, ceiling(Number * 100), floor(Number * 100)) / 100, 2)
```

Comment: What happens if the number is 0.4567, it will print 45.67.

Comment: @rakeeee Why would it print that? `0.4567 * 100 = 45.67` → `floor(45.67) = 45` → `45 / 100 = 0.45` → `format_number(0.45, 2) = '0.45'` --- Other example: `Number = 42` → `42 * 100 = 4200` → `floor(4200) = 4200` → `4200 / 100 = 42` → `format_number(42, 2) = '42.00'`